# Is it possible to run Jupyter Notebook B from Jupyter Notebook A and afterwards saving Outputs of B?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

**Part1:**
I want to execute a Jupyter Notebook B (.ipynb) from another Jupyer Notebook A (also .ipynb).

Here I would like to transmit some variables from notebook A to notebook B, which are needed in notebook B.

The notebook B should simply run from top to bottom with then save. No functions have to be called.

**Part2:**
After that I would like to save the outputs from notebook B in an HTML-file, so no-programmers can watch and analyze the results. (Therefore I want to use jupyter nbconvert notebook_b.ipynb --no-input --no-prompt --to html)

Part 2 has been solved so far, but simply for explanation and better understanding.

Comment: `%run somefile.ipynb`

Comment: Yes, I know %run. but the running notebook b is not saved with new outputs, is it? the outputs are only returned in notebook a. how can variables be passed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jupyter Notebook magics.

```
%store variable_name
```

to store a variable and

```
%store -r variable_name
```

to recall it.

**Jupyter Notebook A**

```
name = "carlo"
%store name
Stored 'name' (str)
```

**Jupyter Notebook B**

```
%store -r name
print(name)
carlo
```

There are some [further examples here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/storemagic.html)